# Why does the Kivy app crash when using the paramiko module?

Tags: python, kivy, paramiko, bcrypt, buildozer

I have an application using paramiko, the application itself is going well, but it crashes when you start it, I understand it's in the paramiko module. I have placed the [white list](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16JId5q49ZMkPlV72xsGmWFXWwAzTo150/view?usp=sharing) next to main.py file and next to the black list file in the *pythonforandroid/bootstraps/sdl2/build folder/*

Part of my spec file:

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
requirements = kivy,kivymd,boto3,botocore,openssl,pyjnius,ecdsa,bcrypt,cryptography,paramiko, android
osx.python_version = 3
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.1
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.whitelist_src = whitelist.txt
```

[log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xHt1IMT2HgWB1b7zX4UMilDD5A5SM5au/view?usp=sharing)

part of log file (which in my opinion causes the app to close)

```
06-04 16:31:49.640 21791 21824 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
06-04 16:31:49.640 21791 21824 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/touchtracer2/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 5, in <module>
06-04 16:31:49.641 21791 21824 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/touchtracer2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
06-04 16:31:49.641 21791 21824 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/touchtracer2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/paramiko/transport.py", line 89, in <module>
06-04 16:31:49.642 21791 21824 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/touchtracer2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 37, in <module>
06-04 16:31:49.643 21791 21824 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/touchtracer2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/paramiko/pkey.py", line 31, in <module>
06-04 16:31:49.644 21791 21824 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/touchtracer2/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
06-04 16:31:49.644 21791 21824 I python  :  ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/bcrypt/_bcrypt.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
06-04 16:31:49.644 21791 21824 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

My app, exclusively for the test

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import boto3
import io
import paramiko
KV = '''
Screen:
    Button:
        id: button
        text: "Start"
        font_size: "18sp"
        on_release: app.start()
'''
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    def start(self):
        print('1')
MainApp().run()
```

[buildozer.spec](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OJjELWkFyDrk9wtxFJIUmyjlVXf275Kg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with the bcrypt recipe. There is no obvious solution, it could be a simple or complicated problem depending on the details.

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to run the application with paramiko, possibly using a non-obvious solution

Comment: When I say there's no obvious solution, I mean it's unlikely anyone will be able to just tell you what to do, you'll need to learn what's going on and debug it. You may be able to get help with this on the kivy discord channels.

Comment: I think this could be closed as invalid. This doesn't provide enough info as it is (needs the `buildozer.spec` and build log`. The issue was resolved in Discord anyway and was that the user overrode the `p4a.source_dir` pointing to his local (outdated) repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated buildozer to version 1.2.0, commented out these lines  `p4a.source_dir = /home/kivy/Repos/python-for-android/` `android.ndk_path` `android.sdk_path`, installed python 3.8, fulfilled this command in the terminal `buildozer android clean` and trimmed this line `requirements = kivy,kivymd,boto3,botocore,openssl,pyjnius,ecdsa,bcrypt,cryptography,paramiko,dateutil,urllib3,jmespath,PyNaCl, android`